# angular.js:13708 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'homeController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-routing

could not reach to homeController(module controller). 
while clicking on "home" link getting error on console that "homeController is not a function; undefined.

So, where i need to register this controller
Thanks,
 Rahul

**twoPageApp.js**

```
 * Created by rahul on 9/24/2016.
 */
(function(){
        angular.module("twoPageApp",["ngRoute"])
            .config(function($routeProvider){
               $routeProvider
                   .when('/home',{
                      templateUrl:'/JS/twoPageAppJS/partials/home.html',
                      controller: 'homeController',
                      resolve:{
                           homeContent:['$http',function($http){
                               return $http.get('/homeContent.json');
                           }]
                       }
                   })
                   .when('/page_one',{
                        templateUrl:'/Js/twoPageAppJS/partials/pageOne.html',
                        controller:'pageOneController',
                        resolve:{
                            homeContent:['$http',function($http){
                                return $http.get('/pageOneContent.json');
                            }]
                        }
                   })
                   .when('/page_two',{
                       templateUrl:'/JS/twoPageAppJS/partials/pageTwo.html',
                       controller:'pageTwoController.js',
                       resolve:{
                           homeContent:['$http',function($http){
                               return $http.get('/pageTwoContent.json');
                           }]
                       }
                   })
            });
    })();
```

**twoPageApp.Controller.js**

```
       (function(){
    angular.module("twoPageApp").controller("tpaController",
        ['$scope',function($scope){
            $scope.name="this is twoPageApp js controller";
        }])
})();
```

**module COntroller(homeController.js)**

```
    /**
 * Created by rahul on 9/24/2016.
 */
(function(){
    angular.module("twoPageApp",[]) //here is the change...
        .controller("homeController",['$scope','$rootScope','homeContent',function($scope,$rootScope,homeContent){

            $rootScope.stub={
                homeContent:homeContent.data
            };
            $scope.hello="rahul";
            console.log("raja");
        }]);
})();
```

**home.jsp**

```
[![<div ng-app="twoPageApp" ng-controller="tpaController">
    <div>
        <a href="#/home">home</a>
        <a href="#/page_one">page One</a>
        <a href="#/page_two">page Two</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>][1]][1]
```

Comment: If you create a jsfiddle, that will be helpful to understand the more problems, I've found few of the problems mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the [] parameter to the `homeController` registration inside `homeController.js`

```
angular.module("twoPageApp") // remove the [] parameter
```

Comment: here it is:-  
(function(){
    angular.module('twoPageApp');
})();

Comment: you still have the same error message ? are you loading ´homeController.js´

Comment: no, i got tpaController is not defined after applying ur suggestn

Comment: look, i am routing the view by clicking on "home" link, for that i created one main controller which will includes all module controller and that main controller will be registered with my app that is "tpaController"

but it is not reaching to my module controller, Do you have any idea why?
Thanks :)

Comment: Could you edit your answer with the latest updated code ? any other error in console or only one ?

Comment: angular.js:13708 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'tpaController' is not a function, got undefined
bro, now getting above error

Comment: edit your Question with your last updated code please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124142/discussion-between-lorenzo-and-rahul-kumar).

Comment: thanks @Lorenzo it was helpful and you have saved many hours of mine

Comment: err, @RahulKumar how did u fix that, i got the same error

Answer (score 0):

You have to register `homeController` the same way you have registered the `tpaController` controller.
You have setup the `$routeProvider` to use the `homeController` on `/home` url, but you haven't registered it anywhere in the code.

Comment: Then can you suggest me where to add/register homeController

Comment: angular.module("twoPageApp.controller")
        .controller("homeController",['$scope','$rootScope','homeContent',functi